# Extract phone number from String

Tags: java, regex, string

The other answers i found don't work for the String I have. My String looks like this:

```
Tel.: 123 12 12 31 12\nMobil: 0173 84 44 962\nE-Mail: info@email.com
```

I would be already enough for me to get the first phone number which occurs. The text is a free text so people can actually put whatever they want, even no number at all.

I tried this

```java
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+).*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(contactText);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        phoneLabel.setText(matcher.group(0));
    }
```

and this regex which is for german numbers

`^(((((((00|\+)49[ \-/]?)|0)[1-9][0-9]{1,4})[ \-/]?)|((((00|\+)49\()|\(0)[1-9][0-9]{1,4}\)[ \-/]?))[0-9]{1,7}([ \-/]?[0-9]{1,5})?)$`

Comment: post your attempts..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match the phone numbers in your example use:

```
(?:\d+\s*)+
```

[See the Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mF0sJ3/1)

---

```
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?:\\d+\\s*)+");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(contactText);
    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        phoneLabel.setText(regexMatcher.group(0));
    }
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Google's [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) library.

It quite easy to use and is more flexible than a handwritten regular expression, as it is aware of country specific rules and can normalize the parsed phone numbers.

Answer (score 2):

tested for your given string

> Tel.: 123 12 12 31 12\nMobil: 0173 84 44 962\nE-Mail: info@email.com

The best and standard way is use [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber). There is a [findNumbers](https://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.html#findNumbers(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.String)) function  you can use. Here is a code snippet

```
public static void  extractPhoneNumber(String input){


    Iterator<PhoneNumberMatch> existsPhone=PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().findNumbers(input, "IN").iterator();

    while (existsPhone.hasNext()){
        System.out.println("Phone == " + existsPhone.next().number());
    }
}
```

Comment: If i try with "hello phone 044 668 18 00" it does not work, for other hand it needs default contry code.

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9 ]+");
```

Although it is not totally correct. It can be used in your case. Don't forget to delete all the blanks.

Comment: There's a blank space in between. You can test regular expressions on http://regexr.com/. I did try on Java though.